# "at this stage" Vs. "in this stage"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

Going through a document for proof reading, I came across the phrase "In this stage, the model is put into operation" and was kind of confused. Mostly I had heard "At this stage ...", i.e. "at" instead of "in". I had a quick look over the net, and could find "In this stage ..." has been also used, however, I am doubtful about:

- This particular usage
- What is the proper use cases of these two phrases

Comment: @Chappo This should be posted as answer. Thank you for such a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of preposition here is a subtle one. It's useful to look at the relevant definitions:

> [**at (1)**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at)
>
> 2. Expressing the time when an event takes place.
>
>    - *‘the children go to bed at nine o'clock’*
>    - *‘his death came at a time when the movement was split’*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

In this particular context, "at" identifies a specific moment in the process/timeline. Compare this with:

> [**in (1)**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)
>
> 2. Expressing a period of time during which an event happens or a situation remains the case.
>
>    - *‘at one o'clock in the morning’*
>    - *‘Nobody who is associated with the bank in that period can come out with any credit.’*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

Thus, "in" is more general and, in the context of your sentence, covers anything that happened *during* that stage.

To some degree the choice of preposition is also influenced by the broader context. If the discussion is about the *stage itself*, then the action happens *in* (during) that stage. If the discussion is focused on the model itself, then you would describe ***at*** what point it's put into operation.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage: While used in a conversation, specifying to the on-going window of time.

In this stage: While used in a conversation, specifying to a physical platform.

Depending on the context, use of the right preposition. If the explanation is about the model in specific, then use "in this stage'. If the explanation is about a certain process or system, use "at this stage".

EDIT: Blunder, Blunder...Shower and Thunder! |Typing error|

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I guess there is a typo, since "in this stage" has come twice